# How to make MutableLiveData<String> to trigger onChanged?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, mutablelivedata

Help me out please.
I want to observe some String using `LiveData`.
`OnChanged()` getting triggered once upon app start, but when Im changing the value of `string1` by button click, `onChange()` does not trigger and information is not updated. `TextView` keeps showing "Wow"
I do everything exactly as described [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata).
The `ViewModel`:

```
class CurrentViewModel : ViewModel() {


val currentName: MutableLiveData<String> by lazy {
    MutableLiveData<String>()
}
}
```

The Fragment:

```
class CurrentFragment : Fragment(R.layout.current_fragment) {
        private val viewModel: CurrentViewModel by viewModels()
       var string1 = "Wow!"

  override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
       val nameObserver = Observer<String> { newName ->
            textview.text = newName        }
       viewModel.currentName.value = string1
       viewModel.currentName.observe(activity!!, nameObserver)


   button.setOnClickListener {
            string1 = "some new string"
        }
}
```

Comment: I think you forgot to update the `LiveData` to change value. According document you mention, you must call the `setValue(T)` method to update the LiveData object from the main thread. If the code is executed in a worker thread, you can use the `postValue(T)` method instead to update the LiveData object. You need to add a syntax to update the `LiveData` in `button` action.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not updating the value of `viewModel.currentName` you should always update the `MutableLiveData`'s value to notify the observers.

Inside of your `OnClickListener` do:

```
button.setOnClickListener {
    // update viewModel value to notify listeners/observers
    viewModel.currentName.value = "some new string"
}
```

Obs: You can remove `string1` as it is useless!

Comment: Thank you. But if I must update `LiveData` manually each time then why do I need `LiveData` at all? I can just update the UI directly instead. Instead of `viewModel.currentName.value = "some new string"` I write `textview.text = "some new string"`, right? It is even shorter =\

Comment: @Waldmann Because `LiveData` gives `Ensures your UI matches your data state`, `No memory leaks`, `No crashes due to stopped activities, `No more manual lifecycle handling`, `Always up to date data`, `Proper configuration changes` and `Sharing resources`. You can find these advantages at official document at [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata).